# Pure HTML/CSS image slider looks different on other browsers than firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, slideshow

I just created a image slider and when I opened the slider in chrome and safari the 3 navigation buttons on the bottom of the slider didn't show up. Here is the code http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/ivxl7z5k

**EDIT**: slider works in all browsers now, but the red bar on top of the slider is still there. If anyone could tell me what I need to edit in the code to remove the gap i would appreciate it

HTML code:

```
<div id="slides">
      <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" class="set" />
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" class="set" />
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3" class="set" />

      <div class="mask">

        <div class="overflow">

          <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/slideshow1.jpg">
          </div>

          <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/slideshow2.jpg">
          </div>

          <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/slideshow3.jpg">
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>


      <div id="controls" onclick="">  
        <label for="slide1"></label>
        <label for="slide2"></label>
        <label for="slide3"></label>
      </div>

    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
      #slides { 
      position:absolute;
      width:1024px; 
      height: 525px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      left: 256px;
      background: #ddd;
    }

    #slides input {

      position: relative;

      left: 30px;
      top: 500px;
    }

    #slides .mask { 
      width:1024px; 
      overflow:hidden; 
      margin:auto; 

    }

    #slides .overflow { 
      width:400%; 
      -webkit-transform:translateZ(0); 
      -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-out; 
      -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-out; 
      -o-transition:all 0.5s ease-out; 
      transition:all 0.5s ease-out; 

    }

    #slides .slide { 
      width: 1024px; 
      height: 525px;  
      float:left; 
      background:#fff; 


    #controls { width:100%;  }

    #controls label { 

      display:none; 
      width:5%; 
      height:60px; 
      opacity:0.3; 
      position:absolute; 
      top:50%; 
      margin-top:-30px; 
      cursor:pointer; 
      background:#000; 
    }

    #controls label:hover { opacity:0.8; }

    #slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2), #slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3); 

    #slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1), #slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try z-index for your radio buttons. For example in their css add z-index:100.

```
#slides input {
      position: relative;
      left: 30px;
      top: 500px;
      z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome and if it works i would appreciate to tick my answer as correct

Comment: just did, do you know how i can remove the grey bar at the top of the slider? even if i remove the `background` on `#slides` in css it still have a gap on top

Comment: if you take a look at this demo http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/ivxl7z5k i added a red color on the top of the slider. If i remove the red color on `#slides` the gap between the header and the slider is still there. 

I want to remove the red gap on the top of the slider

Comment: The radio buttons cause this gap. Try moving the radio buttons after the mask div